# null network connection for Windows 7 and VBox?

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox instance running on Windows 7 for web development. When my laptop has a web connection, everything works fine. I can connect to the VBox instance via its IP address.

However, sometimes I'm in a place where I can't get an internet connection. I would like to connect to the VBox instance ( it's just a shell -- no GUI or browser, and a rather small screen resolution at that ) through the browser and putty in Windows 7. But when Windows doesn't have its own network connection, it doesn't seem to set one up for VBox. I try to connect to the VBox instance through the IP I've assigned it, which works when there is internet, but no go. And FF says it's offline so it won't connect.

It seems to me that I need to set up a null network connection, so that I can set up a little network all inside this laptop. If both the laptop and the VBox have an IP address, then I can access the Vbox.

I'm in South American and the internet connection is very slow, so hopefully I can avoid a solution that involves downloading 10s of megs of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [install a Loopback adapter](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/how-to-install-a-loopback-adapter-in-windows-7/) on the laptop to fake an active connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try a host-only connection: [The fastest way to create a host-only network with virtualbox](http://ptony82.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/the-fastest-way-to-create-host-only-network-with-virtualbox/).